# Pass variable argument list to base constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-functions

Is it possible in C++ to pass a variable argument lists to a base constructor?

I could just copy the code of the base constructor to the derived class, an handle the variable argument list there, but that would lead to unwanted code duplication.

This is what I tried so far:

```
class A{
public:
  A(const char * fmt,...){
    va_list ap;
    va_start( ap, fmt );
    vprintf(fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);
  };
};

class B: public A{
public:
  B(const char * fmt,...):A(fmt){;};
};

int main(){
  B("%d\n",42);
}
```

But the constructor doesn't pass the variable arguments to the base class constructor.

Comment: Related, have you tried used C++ variadic template arguments instead of old-school va_stuff ?

Comment: For C-ellipsis, you have a variant to pass `va_list`, as `printf` has is counterpart `vprintf`. For C++, just use variadic template.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use variadic templates (and drop this C-style stuff):

```
struct A {
     template<typename ... Args>
     A(const char * fmt, Args&& ... args) {
          printf(fmt,std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
     };
};

struct B: public A {
  template<typename ... Args>
  B(const char * fmt, Args&& ... args) : A(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args) ...) {}
};
```

Example:

```
B("Print %d and %s",1,"hello");  //prints "Print 1 and hello"
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c6d97892440963f)

Comment: I was asking for variable arguments lists, as I want to use printf. I know it is possible to implement a printf like function (with typesafety) in C++ using variadic templates, but I haven't found one ...

Comment: sorry, I should have added that ... I'm doing it right now ... done :-)